# Execute a function when a nodejs event is received

Tags: javascript, node.js

I might missing something basic, but here is my goal: I have a small instant chat example based on tutorial found here [Instant Chat for drupal](https://willvincent.com/2012/02/07/building-a-custom-realtime-chat-module-for-drupal-7-part-2/)

The principle is to connect to a nodejs server that basically just broadcast all messages it receives.

I have this function on the client side (inside a drupal tpl.php file):

```js
(function($) {
  var myNick = 'me';
  var socket = io.connect('http://<?php print $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] ?>:8081');

  socket.on('connect', function() {
    $('#chat').addClass('connected');
  });

  socket.on('user message', message);

  function message(from, msg) {
    if (msg == 'GO') { 
      ** EXECUTE A FUNCTION HERE **
    } else { //display the message and sender
      $('#lines').append($('<p>').append(from, msg));
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#send-message').submit(function() {
      message(myNick, $('#messageinput').val());
      socket.emit('user message', $('#messageinput').val());
      clear();
      $('#lines').get(0).scrollTop = 10000000;
      return false;
    });

    function clear() {
      $('#message').val('').focus();
    };

  });
})(jQuery);
```

When I send a message with content =GO, the submit is executed, the message(..,..) function is called and my specific function is executed properly.

But when I receive a GO message, the socket.on event triggers,  message() function is called, but my specific function is NOT executed.

Any Idea how I can fix this?

Many thanks for your help.
Michael.

Comment: Add some `console.log()`'s in your message function, and check the output. Perhaps there is some whitespace around `msg`, or your parameters are reversed/incorrect.

Comment: Think issue is that, you have 2 arguments(from, msg) for message function and you are passing only one here : socket.emit('user message', $('#messageinput').val());. Try to console.log both from and msg in your message function.

Comment: Another test: when I receive a GO, If I modify the content of the GO message for example, directly inside the message function it works. But if I call a function that modifies the msg content, then it is not executed.

Could it be related to the fact that the message() function is called in one hand from a function declared in $(document).ready, and in the other hand in an event declared before the $(document) .ready?

Comment: Try, this emit syntax in your submit function instead of current one.
socket.emit('user message', {
     from: 'me',
        msg: $('#messageinput').val()
        
    });

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but the problem is not from within socket.emit. This one works well. The problem is inside the message function. When "message" is called from socket.emit, it executes the code inside "myfunction" if the message is GO, but, in case of GO message reception, the call to message from within socket.on('user message', message) does not execute the myfunction code... In case of message received, the socket.emit is not used.